# How To get a Custom field Value of a client using FollowUpBoss Api

Tags: php, json, api, curl, php-curl

I am trying to get the value of a custom date field from followupboss trough the APi,

Here is my code which is get all custom fields informations, but I want to specify the response to a specific client (By ID, Name or Email)

```
<?php
const FUB_API_KEY = '?????????????????????????????';
$headers = array(
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode(FUB_API_KEY . ":"),
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
"X-System: ??????????",
"X-System-Key: ?????????????????????????",
);
//$data = array(
//"person" => array( 
//    "" => "" ,
//),
//);
$ch = curl_init('https://api.followupboss.com/v1/customFields');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
exit('cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch) . "\n");
}
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($response) { echo json_encode(json_decode($response));}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To return lead information including their custom field values i used the following:

```
https://api.followupboss.com/v1/people/ID?fields=allFields
```

(ID) is replaced by user profile ID (e.g. 70114)